# Nesting layouts and dynamically updating them

Tags: android, layout

I want to nest a `TableLayout` inside a `RelativeLayout` and later dynamically edit the TableLayout in my Java Code.

My XML-File looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_load_date"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".LoadDateActivity" >

<!-- few buttons and textviews -->

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_load_date_table_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button" >
    </TableLayout> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Java Code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_load_date);
    //Do something with my Buttons and TextViews(this works fine)

tblLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_load_date_table_layout);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
if (v.getId() == R.id.button_calc) {
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfEntries.size(); i++) {
        Entry temp = listOfEntries.get(i);

        if (temp.getDate().getTime() >= startDate.getTime()
                && temp.getDate().getTime() <= endDate.getTime()) {

            TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
            TextView comm = new TextView(this);
            comm.setText(listOfEntries.get(i).getComment());
            TextView val = new TextView(this);
            val.setText(String.valueOf(listOfEntries.get(i).getValue()));

            LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(0,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);
            tr.setLayoutParams(params);
            tr.addView(comm);
            tr.addView(val);
            tblLayout.addView(tr);
        }
    }
         tblLayout.invalidate(); //Shouldn't this redraw the entire TableLayout and therefore adding my TableRows? This is not working.
}
}
```

Through various tests with TextViews and Toasts I have gathered that the tblLayout should be filled and the TableRows are added to the Layout, the only thing that is not working is the "repainting" of my Layout. How do I achieve that?

### Edit:

Apparently the thing that made this not work was actually the LayoutParams given to the TableRow, once I commented those out I atleast got it printed to the screen. They are however not where I expect them to be.
I expected them to be below the buttons, instead they are in the top left corner on top of the buttons. This leads me to believe that the TableLayout is actually the same size as the RelativeLayout but is layered above the RelativeLayout. The error should therefor lie in my XML-File. What height do I need to give my TableLayout to make this work the way I expect?

### Edit2:

I needed to add the `android:layout_below` attribute to my TableLayout, works as a charm now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the method "requestLayout()"

Call this when something has changed which has invalidated the layout of this view. This will schedule a layout pass of the view tree.

Comment: Works great, thank you. Could you please see my edit? I experienced another problem.